# query.next() returning false

Tags: sql, qt

I have used the `query.next()` function inside my code, but its returning false. 
I even checked in the database, there are 4 records present. But the code shows only one.
However if i use `query.next()` before the code of `query.valid()` then it doesn't show any record
Please help

```
  qDebug() << "entering payment: get all the unchecked invoices for user: " + user;
  QStringList tmp;
  QSqlQuery query(m_storageUserManager->database());
  m_storageUserManager->dumpTable(m_invoiceInfoTable);
  m_storageUserManager->dumpTable(m_invoiceUserTable);
  qDebug()<<"THE NAME OF THE INVOICE USER TABLE_----=-----------------"<<m_invoiceInfoTable;
  qDebug()<<"THE NAME OF THE INVOICE USER TABLE_----=-----------------"<<m_invoiceUserTable;
  query.prepare("SELECT invoice FROM "+ m_invoiceInfoTable +" WHERE invoice = (SELECT
                 invoice FROM "+ m_invoiceUserTable +" WHERE user=:user)");
//  query.prepare("SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceInfoTable + ","+ m_invoiceUserTable +" WHERE " + m_invoiceInfoTable + ".user = " + m_invoiceUserTable + ".:user");
  query.bindValue(":user", user);
  query.exec();
  query.first();
  qDebug()<<"Unchecked invoices done!!! " ;
  if(query.isValid()) {
    do {
      tmp.append(query.value(0).toString());    //as the value returned by value() is a QVariant so we need to change it to String.
    } while(query.next());
  } else
    tmp.append("No Unchecked invoice in the database");
  return tmp;
```

Comment: Are all four records for the same user? Does `query.first()` return `true`? What does `query.size()` return?

Comment: If the subquery returns more than one row, the outer `where` should have a `in` rather than `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the query was successful you should test the return value of either QSqlQuery::exec() or QSqlQuery::isActive() before trying to call first/next/last (when you pass the query string to the constructor of QSqlQuery, the query is already executed, so, you need to use QSqlQuery::isActive()).

*first()*, *next()* and *last()* return true if they positioned the query on a valid record, you don't have to test *isValid()* separately. Since *first()* is a positioning function too, you can read the value without calling *next()* directly after, unless you want to skip the first record.

Since you may want to add fields from the the "invoice-info" table to your query, I kept the subquery (with IN instead of = as Mat already answered in the comment).

```
query.prepare(QString("SELECT invoice FROM %1 WHERE invoice "
                      "IN (SELECT invoice FROM %2 WHERE user=:user)")
              .arg(m_invoiceInfoTable, m_invoiceUserTable));    
/*
// Or with an inner join
query.prepare(QString("SELECT %1.invoice FROM %1 "
              "INNER JOIN %2 ON %1.invoice = %2.invoice "
              "WHERE user=:user").arg(m_invoiceInfoTable, m_invoiceUserTable));*/    
query.bindValue(":user", user);

if (!query.exec()) { 
    tmp.append("Query error: %1" + query.lastError().text());
} else if (!query.first()) { 
    tmp.append("No Unchecked invoice in the database");
} else {
    do {
        tmp.append(query.value(0).toString());
    } while(query.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
query.prepare("SELECT invoice FROM " + m_invoiceInfoTable + " WHERE user=:user");
```

Comment: I am sorry for not posting the db structure,
But actually there is no user field in the invoice info table which is connected to the user field using the invoiceUser Table